# median calculation in boxplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, statistics

When I try to output the median value of a dataset with `\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median}}` in a boxplot, the computed value is not the actual median (see below: 2.5 instead of 3). Is there a way to fix this? I'd prefer not to calculate all the boxplot values (median, whiskers, ...) externally. (I just realise that the box is also misaligned.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{input.csv}
name,value
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{input.csv}\mydata
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot/draw/median/.code={
        \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every median/.try]
            (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},0)
            --
            node[right, font=\tiny] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median}}}
            (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},1);
    },
}

\begin{axis}
\addplot+[boxplot] table[x=value] {\mydata};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Boxplot with median]

Comment: Btw.: I removed the first line and it has the same result. The pgfplots manual states: "The first line will be checked if it contains numerical data. If there is a column in the first
line which is no number, the complete line is considered to be a header which contains column
names."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this corresponds to the definition given in *Prepared Box Plots and Common Options* (see p. 497 of the `pgfplots` manual for version 1.16). Here, (1/2)⋅(x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>) = (1/2)⋅(2 + 3) = 2.5. This expression is chosen because you have N = 5, thus with p = 0.5, Np = 0.5⋅N is not an integer.

That said, assuming your data is already sorted, it is not very difficult to compute the median according to the definition of your choice:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{input.csv}
name,value
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\computeMedian}[3]{%
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}%
  \let\@nbRows\pgfplotsretval
  \ifodd\pgfplotsretval\relax
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\the\numexpr(\@nbRows-1)/2}{#2}\of{#1}%
    \let#3\pgfplotsretval
  \else
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\the\numexpr \@nbRows/2 - 1}{#2}\of{#1}%
    \let\@firstValue\pgfplotsretval
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\the\numexpr \@nbRows/2}{#2}\of{#1}%
    \let\@secondValue\pgfplotsretval
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{0.5*(\@firstValue + \@secondValue)}%
  \fi
}

\pgfplotsset{
    my median/.code 2 args={%
      \computeMedian{#1}{#2}{\@tmp}%
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/my median}{\@tmp}%
    },
    boxplot/draw/median/.code={
        \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every median/.try]
            (boxplot box cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/my median},0)
            --
            node[right, font=\tiny]
              {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/my median}}}
            (boxplot box cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/my median},1);
    },
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{input.csv}\mydata

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[boxplot, my median={\mydata}{value}] table[x=value] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{input.csv}
name,value
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5
f,6
\end{filecontents}
```

you would get instead:

[image]

If your data is not already sorted, you can create a new table from the one you have, sorted according to the column of your choice, with:

```latex
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={column}]\resulttable\sourcetable
```

then you can apply the previous method to `\resulttable`. Another option would be to dump all values to an `expl3` `seq` variable and use `\seq_sort:Nn`.